# getting 500 internal error while ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting 500 internal error, while passing data in ajax. click function is working fine, if i change ajax page its working fine but current page not working..

```
<script>
        function saveBooking()
            {
                var usernamesend = document.getElementById("username").value;
                if(usernamesend=="")
                {
                    alert("Please fill Name");
                    return false;
                }
                var emailsend = document.getElementById("email").value;
                if(emailsend=="")
                {
                    alert("Please fill Email");
                    return false;
                }
                var phonesend = document.getElementById("phone").value;
                if(phonesend=="")
                {
                    alert("Please fill Phone Number");
                    return false;
                }
                var dateokk = '<?php echo $newDate123; ?>';
                var paymentMethod = "spot";
                var slotPrice = document.getElementById("slotPrice").value;
                var slotTime = document.getElementById("slotTime").value;
                var totalPrice = '<?php echo $originalSlotFee; ?>';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "savebookingajax.php",
                    data: {usernamesend:usernamesend,emailsend:emailsend,phonesend:phonesend,dateokk:dateokk,paymentMethod:paymentMethod,slotPrice:slotPrice,slotTime:slotTime,totalPrice:totalPrice},
                    success : function(res){
                        alert(res);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: savebookingajax.php

    <?php 
    include("adminpage/connect.php");
    $username=$_REQUEST['usernamesend'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['emailsend'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phonesend'];
    $dateokk=$_REQUEST['dateokk'];
    $paymentMethod=$_REQUEST['paymentMethod'];
    $slotPrice=$_REQUEST['slotPrice'];
    $slotTime=$_REQUEST['slotTime'];
    $totalPrice=$_REQUEST['totalPrice'];

Comment: $insert_staff=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `booking` (`slotId`, `slotTime`, `bookingDate`, `priceTotal`, `name`, `mobile`, `email`, `address`, `paymentMethod`, `createdDate`, `modifiedDate`) VALUES ('$originalSlot','','$newDate123','$TotalPriceFinal','$username','$phone','$email','','$paymentMethod',NOW(),'')"); 
 if(!~$insert_staff)
 { echo "Fail"; 
  } 
 
  else
  {
   echo "Pass"; 
  }

Comment: Under the tags of your question, there is the `edit` link.  Click that and add the additional stuff to your question, not the comments.

Comment: @Rajeshk-Add your php code from comments in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your keys in `data` are wrong**

```
data: {usernamesend:usernamesend,emailsend:emailsend,phonesend:phonesend,dateokk:dateokk,paymentMethod:paymentMethod,slotPrice:slotPrice,slotTime:slotTime,totalPrice:totalPrice},
```

Keys `usernamesend, emailsend, phonesend, dateokk, paymentMethod, slotPrice, totalPrice` will replace with the actual values of element of html page while on php side you are using these as a key.

Use keys as String values:

```
          data: {"usernamesend":usernamesend,"emailsend":emailsend,"phonesend":phonesend,"dateokk":dateokk,"paymentMethod":paymentMethod,"slotPrice":slotPrice,"slotTime":slotTime,"totalPrice":totalPrice},
```